# Как вывести кириллицу в ActiveForm в качестве названия самой формы Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Как вывести кириллицу в ActiveForm  в качестве названия самой формы Yii2?

Есть поле для ввода, называется "Name" а нужно назвать "Имя".

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

   <?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>

   <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>


   <div class="form-group">
       <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
   </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: В модели переименовать по-русски поля

Comment: ошибка возникает, ошибка атрибутов. Версия Yii2 последняя стабильная

Comment: Что за ошибка атрибутов? Может в вопросе это тоже напишите, что изменяли и какая полная ошибка появляется.

Answer (score 3):

Более верным решением думаю будет использование метода Model::attributeLabels()

```
public function attributeLabels() {
    return [
        'name' => 'Ваше имя'
    ];
}
```

Вы ведь не будете при выводе формы к модели постоянно прописывать название поля? Проще один раз написать

Comment: Я это сразу человеку предложил. он написал что ошибка выскакивает. Какая и где - он так и не сказал. Но лично я с вами согласен

Answer (score 0):

Good worked!

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->label('Ваше имя'); ?>
```

Comment: Я не могу это сделать потому что я сам ответил на свой вопрос.